# Cucumber Selenium (Java) - PageFactory - NullPointException getting URL

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, constants, factory

Hi community: I am stuck in the next issue:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pages.Page_First.getURL(Page_First.java:31)
    at stepdefs.Step_First.I_go_to_Google(Step_First.java:22)
    at ✽.I go to Google (src/test/resources/features/first.feature:9)
```

This is my Feature:

```
Feature: Navigation Test

  As a user, bla, bla, bla...

  Scenario: Search google.com to verify google search is working

    Given I go to Google
    When I query for "<search>" cucumber spring selenium
    And click search
    Then google page title should become the first page
```

This next is my **DriverClass**

```
public class DriverClass implements Constants {

    // Take the instance of WebDriver
    protected static WebDriver driver;

    //Initialize a log
    protected static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BasePage.class.getName());


    public static WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {

        String browser = ReadProperties.getPropertyValue(key_browser);


        if(browser.equals("chrome")) {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

        } else if(browser.equals("firefox")) {
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        } else if(browser.equals("ie")) {
                WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        } else if(browser.equals("edge")) {
            WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
            driver = new EdgeDriver();

        } else {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver","/usr/bin/safaridriver");
            driver = new SafariDriver();
        }
        return driver;
    }
}
```

This other is my **DriverInitializer** Class

```
public class DriverInitializer extends DriverClass {


    @Before
    public void initialize() throws IOException {

        log.info("-----> Proceed to initialize driver <-----");

        driver = DriverClass.initializeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        if (driver == null) {
            log.info("-----> Driver did not initialize correctly <-----");
        }
    }

    @After
    public void close(){
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

My **Page** Class:

```
public class Page_First extends BasePage implements Constants {

    public Page_First() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////WEB ELEMENTS//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @FindBy(name = "q")
    private WebElement searchText;

    @FindBy(name="btnK")
    private WebElement searchButton;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////BASE METHODS//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void getURL() throws IOException {

        String url = ReadProperties.getPropertyValue(key_url);
        driver.get(url);
```

And My **Step Definition**:

```
public class Step_First {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    private Page_First page_first = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Page_First.class);


    @Given("I go to Google")
    public void I_go_to_Google () throws IOException {

        page_first.getURL();
    }
```

I know that the problem is in the next pice of code (Page):

```
String url = ReadProperties.getPropertyValue(key_url);
driver.get(url);
```

By the way: This is my **Constants** class

public interface Constants {

```
String key_url = "url";
String key_browser = "browser";
```

}

Please, I need your help. Thanks in advance

Updated: This is my file for reading property files:

```
public class ReadProperties {

    public static final String filePath = "src/main/resources/data/config.properties";


    public static String getPropertyValue(String key) throws IOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        prop.load(fis);
        fis.close();
        return prop.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to find out the problem from the stacktrac, line 31 is points on what line?
I think the problem is with reading the property, where are you reading the property from and what's the value of key_value ? You shouldn't use constants as an interface, try to create another type of resource file or a class with static fields according to your implementation.

Comment: I updated with my ReadProperties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it doesn't find your path. Try this:

```
public class ReadProperties {

    public static String getPropertyValue(String key) throws IOException {
        String filePath = "src/main/resources/data/config.properties";
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try (input) {
            prop.load(input);
            return prop.getProperty(key);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```